# KendoUI Dataviz series markers on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have been using KendoUI Dataviz for only a short time, and have found I am able to customize it in almost anyway to meet my needs except one. I have two different charts where certain series just happen to have more than one point with the same plots. (dynamic data) I am unable to see all of the tooltips for all of the markers (since they are on top of each other), which means I am also unable to use the seriesClick or seriesHover events on those that are hidden. I have searched Kendo's forums, Stackflow and even Google but can't find anything specifically on the unreachable issue. Kendo's forums mention hiding the tooltip and making a custom one, but I haven't found anything that addressed the fact that some series markers are just unreachable and I need to reach them to use those events. Does anyone have an idea on how I can reach all markers for the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to figure out a way to show "hidden" data points.  I've had to do something similar in the past, and used a custom tooltip template function. In the function I grab the category (x value in my scatter chart sample), and get all matching items from the datasource.  Then just put together some sort of list/etc. and return that. You can always go super fancy and make a box with tabs and the whole nine yards to show each dataItem on that particular point.

See sample on jsbin

http://jsbin.com/ONuQUgiY/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I had missed something, and there was another way, possibly built-in,  besides a function-but you're function is actually much cleaner than I would have thought...so I guess I'll be just fine with a function. Thanks again!